# Is there a way to invoke from a Makefile a custom Zsh function compiled into a digest?

Tags: makefile, zsh

I developed a simple Zsh function and compiled it into a zwc digest file.  I already have the zwc digest file path in FPATH (i.e. fpath).

I've tried setting the SHELL variable as /usr/bin/zsh but the following error is printed after invoking make:

`zsh:1: command not found: bckpfile`

How can I invoke the function `bckpfile` from a Makefile recipe?